# Handshake when HTTP(S) POST delivers data to the server

Tags: python, performance, post, curl, https

I am `POST`ing to a certain `https`endpoint using a `python` script and `pycurl` (`BASIC` authentication, connection kept open over calls) and experience a strange behaviour:

- When `POST`ing from a client with high bandwith network connection (LAN or my uberspace) I get response times that are weakly dependent on payload size (e.g. 1 kB is `POST`ed in 40 millis, 20 kB require some 70 millis).
- When connected from home (cable, 25 MBit/s downstream, 1 MBit/s upstream) I am experiencing not only slower response tim (which I was expecting), but also a much heavier dependency (namely 60 millis for 1 kB and constantly increasing to 400+ millis for 20 kB). This seems independent whether I post from a cabled Raspberry Pi or a Wifi connected i5 computer, so I am concluding the issue is the upstream bandwith.

But: The respective response times recorded by the client are also recorded by the server (a `tomcat` I believe), with a delta of, say, 3 millis.

**Question:** How can this be explained from the respective setup?

I was thinking that, of course, a slow connection will take more time to deliver payload to the server. Therefore I do not have a big problem with the response times itself. I merely have an issue with my lack of understanding:

I was thinking that the client 'deliveres' the payload to the server over the network and then the server will start to process it once it is 'there'. Therefore I was expecting the client to record a longer response time than the host does (the difference of the readings being the time spent 'on the internet'). The delta should be bigger when the connection is low bandwith and getting smaller with increasing bandwith. But it seems that I have some deep misunderstanding of how `POST` and network connections work. I have spent the night searching for more information about the handshake of client (`curl` in this case) and webserver (supposedly `tomcat` in this case) but while I found [great trivia](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~bsy/coke.history.txt) about the early days of networking, I was not able to retrieve anything allowing me a deeper understanding of that handshake. I would appreciate any hints or pointers how to dig in.